# CSS margin top from sibling element not parent

Tags: html, css

I have got this html

```
 <div class="ChatDiv">
    <div class="chatdiv_ fm">
            <span>uhygtfgyhujiuhygt i uytr yui jhuygtfr</span>
    </div>
    <div class="chatdiv_ fm" style="margin-top:148;">
           <span>t</span>
    </div>

<div class="chatdiv_ fm" style="margin-top:214;">
                        <span>t</span>
          </div>
   </div>
```

And this css

```
.ChatDiv{
    width: 800px;
    height: 480px;
    overflow: auto;
    margin-left: 350px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: white;
    margin-top: 80px;
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 11px black;
}
.fm{
    position: relative;
    font-family: Nbutler;
    font-size: 20px;
    float: right;
    background: #2196f3;
    max-width: 400px;
    color: white;
    margin-left: -432px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    span{
        display: block;
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
        max-width: 400px;    
    }
}
```

And the problem is when i have margin top on `fm` elements it takes this margin from the top.Not from the sibling element and i do not how many `fm` elements i will have so i can not put the same margin-top for all fm elements

Comment: A reduced example in a jsfiddle/jsbin would help a alot...you have a lot unnecessary (and badly formatted) code, which makes it unnecessarily hard for us to help you...

Comment: I created a simple example you could find useful: http://codepen.io/karlisup/pen/RRJGBJ

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use absolute position, then it will happen all the time, because it will a Div, which has position relative as a borders, and your divs with position absolute just "doesnt exit".

There's no need to use `position: absolute` for these divs. Just remove float, position, margins and you will good to go.

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sey4121b/

Comment: withou position absolute for chatdiv it affects the heading

Comment: Can you paste a jsFiddle url with your FULL current code? That would be easier. Other way, you can use `:first-child` and then set it to `position: relative`. I really need a copy of your current code.

Answer (score 0):

Added Example where margins are calculated from siblings.

```css
.container{
 width: 500px;
 height: 300px;
 margin: 16px auto;
 padding: 16px;
 
 border-radius: 6px;
 border: 1px solid black;
}

.list {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 16px;
 float: right;
 width: 50%;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: tomato;
}
.list__elem {
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 height: 42px;
 margin-bottom: 16px;
 padding-left: 16px;
 
 border: 1px solid olive;
 line-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <ul class="list">
  <li class="list__elem">Elem 1</li>
  <li class="list__elem">Elem 2</li>
  <li class="list__elem">Elem 3</li>
  <li class="list__elem">Elem 4</li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I think that inline margin styles and lack of element grouping makes it hard to understand the example.

Good luck ;)